# GWT designer in eclipse 4.2.2 not working or workflow changed?

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

In junoSR2  there seems to be no more posibillity of creating a new gwt designer form or any other widget directly. The answer here (  [GWT Designer not working with Eclipse 4.2 service release 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370165/gwt-designer-not-working-with-eclipse-4-2-service-release-2)  ) details a workaround for this. Is this the new  workflow for when you use gwt designer  or am i doing something wrong?